# Can I trigger a Gitlab CI/CD rebuild if global variable changes?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, cicd

I have several projects that uses a key, which changes every so often. Is there a way to trigger a rebuild of those projects when I change the key variable?

I'm trying to use the rules:changes keyword:

```
run:
    script:
        - echo $KEY
    rules:
        - if: $KEY
          changes:
            - $KEY
          when: always
```

Answer (score 1):

No, You cannot. GitLab Runners will read your .gitlab-ci.yaml scripts and execute them on demand. That means the GitLab Runner will be invoked on demand and it is not actively listening to the change of a particular variable.

But as an alternate solution, you can write a script and place it somewhere (in your local or in the runner machine or anywhere). and the script should check if any changes in the variable and if yes, trigger the pipeline remotely using [GitLab CI APIs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/pipelines.html#create-a-new-pipeline) . Then you can add your script in corn job to run the script in particular interval and check for changes in variable

Comment: I would think you could use a scheduled pipeline as well, in place of a cron job. Then just have the scheduled pipeline run the full pipeline if a variable has changed. It would take some tweaking to get it right.